# We have 3 instances of magento how they can interact with each other also we have to use only one cart for and 1 ui for users taking these 3 instance

Tags: magento

We have 3 instances of Magneto installed ,how can we synchronise 
  customers between those and we want only on cart for all websites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to merge all three into one. The merge is not something really easy and you'll have to prepare it some time ahead !